# Group by date and and check for continuous dates

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, common-table-expression

I have a set of data like this

```
date1       Price  Availability  ServiceID
2012-10-01  50     1             5
2012-10-02  60     1             5
2012-10-03  60     1             5
2012-10-04  60     1             5
2012-10-06  60     1             5
2012-10-07  60     0             5
2012-10-08  60     1             5
```

Now I want to check what is the total price, min availability and serviceid for a particular period

For example

```
from 2012-10-01 to 2012-10-03 results would be 170, availability 1 and serviceID 5
from 2012-10-06 to 2012-10-08 results would be 180, availability 0! and serviceID 5
from 2012-10-04 to 2012-10-06 results would be 120, availability 1! and serviceID 5 BUT there is a date missing so availability is 0!
```

I tried something like

```
select date1, sum(price), min(availability), service from #t
group by date1, price, availability, service
having count(date1) = datediff(day, @startdate, @enddate)
```

That does not work because if I group by date1, then count in not valid. Dont know how to get sum, min availability and check continuous dates.

**EDIT**
In case I want a results set to contain detailed spec. and filter out results with min(availability) = 0 or noncontinuous date

```
For example
from 2012-10-01 to 2012-10-03 results would be 170, availability 1 and serviceID 5

date1       Price  Availability  ServiceID
    2012-10-01  50     1             5
    2012-10-02  60     1             5
    2012-10-03  60     1             5

from 2012-10-06 to 2012-10-08 results would be 180, availability 0! and serviceID 5
date1       Price  Availability  ServiceID

from 2012-10-04 to 2012-10-06 results would be 120, availability 1! and serviceID 5 BUT 
date1       Price  Availability  ServiceID
```

Comment: How could result from 2012-10-04 to 2012-10-06 be 180 if there are 2 values with 60 each? Do you need a 'fake' 60 for missing date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select  sum(price) As TotalPrice, 
        service,
        Case When Count(*) = DateDiff(Day, @Startdate, @EndDate) + 1 
                Then Min(Availability)
                Else 0 End As Availability
from    #T
Where   Date1 >= @StartDate
        And Date1 <= @endDate
group by service
```

By filtering the date in a where clause based on dates, and not grouping by the date, this allows you to get a count or rows which you can then match to the date diff.  Note that you need to add 1 to the date diff because DateDiff from yesterday to today is only 1 but would represent 2 rows in your source data.

I should also mention that this is not actually checking for continuous dates.  It's simply looking for a corresponding number of rows to match the calculated number of days.

Based on your comment and your edit, you may want to try this derived table solution.

```
Select  T.date1,
        SummaryData.TotalPrice,
        SummaryData.Availability,
        T.Service
From    #T T
        Inner Join (
            select  sum(price) As TotalPrice, 
            service,
                Case When Count(*) = DateDiff(Day, @Startdate, @EndDate) + 1 
                     Then Min(Availability)
                     Else 0 End As Availability
            from    #T
            Where   Date1 >= @StartDate
                    And Date1 <= @endDate
            group by service
            Having Case When Count(*) = DateDiff(Day, @Startdate, @EndDate) + 1 
                        Then Min(Availability)
                        Else 0 End = 1 
            ) As SummaryData
            On T.Service = SummaryData.Service
Where   Date1 >= @StartDate
        And Date1 <= @endDate
```

Comment: basically i would need a cte or a temp table. it cannot be solved in one query?

Comment: It's possible to create the same output I show above without using a CTE, but it may not be possible to include the details without using a CTE unless you are on a newer version of SQL Server.  What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If there wasn't for curveball with missing dates, query would be quite simple:

```
SELECT SUM(price), MIN(availability) AS Availibility, MIN(serviceID) AS serviceID FROM #t
WHERE date1 BETWEEN @Startdate AND @enddate
```

Howere, finding missing dates requires one additional CTE, I'll use idea from [t-sql get all dates between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946121/t-sql-get-all-dates-between-2-dates) and it can look somehting like this:

```
;WITH dates AS (
  SELECT @startdate AS dt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, dt)
    FROM dates s
   WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, dt) <= @enddate
)
SELECT SUM(price), 
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dates WHERE dt NOT IN (SELECT date1 FROM #t WHERE date1 BETWEEN @Startdate AND @enddate)) THEN 0
    ELSE MIN(availability) 
END AS Availibility, 
MIN(serviceID) AS serviceID FROM #t
WHERE date1 BETWEEN @Startdate AND @enddate
```

Comment: While I was typing G Mastros also posted a solution which I like better then mine :) but decided to post this one as well. Doesn't hurt to look from two sides.