# How to display the dates between from_date and to_date column in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Example:

```
Table A

From_Date     To_Date        
2016-02-22    2016-02-29


Output
-------

2016-02-23
2016-02-24
2016-02-25
2016-02-26
2016-02-27
2016-02-28
```

The output should come like this.

Both columns are in same table A.

I want to display the dates that are in between these two columns.

Comment: how about using google before asking on stackoverflow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [t-sql get all dates between 2 dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946121/t-sql-get-all-dates-between-2-dates)

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  Can you edit your question to include all the relevant columns from your table?  Can you also include some sample rows?  Finally can you show us the output you would expect that sample to return?  See the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more on providing helpful sample data.

Comment: This is marked as duplicate. However, I would recommend the answer from Martin Smith over the select answer. A tally table is much more efficient than a recursive cte for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You mean:

```
select *
from table_name
where from_date >= '2016-02-22' and to_date <= '2016-05-16'
```

Comment: I want to display only the dates that are lying between these two dates.

Comment: What is your mean?

Answer (score 0):

If `From_Date` and `To_Date` are variables:

```
DECLARE @From_Date date = '2016-02-22',
        @To_Date date = '2016-05-16'

SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE DateField between @From_Date and @To_Date
```

If not then:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE DateField between '2016-02-22' and '2016-05-16'
```

In another table:

```
SELECT y.*
FROM YourTable y
INNER JOIN TableWithDate d
    ON y.DateField between d.From_Date and d.To_Date
```

To get output you want with recursive CTE (assuming that in `[Table A]` is string with `'2016-02-22'`, `'2016-02-29'` values for `From_Date`, `To_Date`):

```
;WITH recurs AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,From_Date) as date_, To_Date
    FROM [Table A]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,date_), To_Date
    FROM recurs r
    WHERE date_ < DATEADD(day,-1,To_Date)
)

SELECT date_
FROM recurs
```

Output:

```
date_
2016-02-23
2016-02-24
2016-02-25
2016-02-26
2016-02-27
2016-02-28
```

Comment: Here From_Date and To_date are Columns.

Comment: In another table? Add this to my answer

Comment: No both column(From_Date & To_Date) are in single table. I want to display only the dates between these two dates.

Comment: Well, then what output do you need? A table with 1 column with dates between those two dates.

Comment: I have displayed the output too ...check out that

Comment: I add this to my answer.