# sql - generate random date, exluding weekends

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I would like to ask you for a help with the query. I´m trying to get list of random dates from 7.2.2016 - 14.2.2016, but I would like to exclude from it 11. and 12.2.2016, which will be weekends.

This is, what I have:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 8), '2016-02-07')
```

I´m using SQL server 2016.

and the dates should be allocated randomly to other columns:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgAR0.png)

SMS_send_day should be those dates, excluding 11.2. and 12.2.

Thank you for your advices!

Comment: did you mean a list like 02/07/2016,02/08/2016 to 02/12/2016 not 11 and 12? total 6 rows?

Comment: Yes, I did and it should be randomly allocated to the rest of columns as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but this gets you a single date excluding the two you asked for. I assume you meant 2017, because those days weren't weekends in 2016.

```
declare @date date
while 1=1
begin
    select @date = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 8), '2017-02-07')
    if @date not in ('2/11/2017', '2/12/2017')
        break   
end
select @date
```

**Edit** Saw the comment...If a list is needed you can try something like this: 
[t-sql get all dates between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946121/t-sql-get-all-dates-between-2-dates) and then just use a where clause to filter out the weekend dates.

Answer (score 0):

If you get yourself a [calendar table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/30/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/) and you have a very simple query on your hands `

```
SELECT TOP 1 Date 
FROM Calendar 
WHERE IsWeekday = 1 
AND Date >= @StartDate 
AND Date <= @EndDate 
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

You could always generate the dates on the fly though:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

DECLARE @Start DATE = '20160207',
        @End DATE = '20160214';

WITH Calendar (Date) AS
(   SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @Start, @End) + 1)
            DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) - 1, @Start)
    FROM    (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n1 (N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n2 (N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n3 (N)
)
SELECT TOP 1 Date 
FROM Calendar 
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date) NOT IN (6, 7)
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Here the calendar CTE cross joins 3 table valued constructors to generate a maximum of 1,000 rows (10 x 10 x 10), then limits that to the number of days required using

```
TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @Start, @End) + 1)
```

Then generates a list of dates onward from the start by using `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate values from 1 to n. So the basic element is:

```
DECLARE @Start DATE = '20160207',
        @End DATE = '20160214';

WITH Calendar (Date) AS
(   SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @Start, @End) + 1)
            DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) - 1, @Start)
    FROM    (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n1 (N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n2 (N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n3 (N)
)
SELECT Date 
FROM Calendar
```

Which gives:

```
Date
------------
2016-02-07
2016-02-08
2016-02-09
2016-02-10
2016-02-11
2016-02-12
2016-02-13
```

It is then a simple case of removing weekends with `WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date) NOT IN (6, 7)` and selecting a random row with `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY NEWID()`. As as aside, when using something setting sensitive like `DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ...)` you should **always** explicitly set the value you need rather than relying on defaults.

I may have misunderstood your requirements though, this last step is not necessary if you just want a list of all the dates

Answer (score 0):

A Calendar or Tally table would do the trick, but I often use a TVF to create dynamic date/time ranges.  It is parameter driven, you define the Date/Time Range, DatePart and Increment

**Example**

```
Declare @D1 date = '2016-02-07'
Declare @D2 date = '2016-02-14'

Select Top 1 D=RetVal
 From  [dbo].[udf-Range-Date](@D1,@D2,'DD',1)
 Where DatePart(DW,RetVal) not in (7,1)
 Order By NewID()
```

**Returns**

```
D
2016-02-11 00:00:00.000
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. I have used Date & Convert Functions.

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0
WHILE (@i<=7)
BEGIN
 DECLARE @T TABLE
 (
    [DATE] DATE
 )
 INSERT INTO @T SELECT CONVERT (DATE,DATEADD(DAY,@i,'2016-02-07'))
 SET @i = @i+1
 IF(CONVERT (DATE,DATEADD(DAY,@i,'2016-02-07')) ='2016-02-11' OR CONVERT (DATE,DATEADD(DAY,@i,'2016-02-07')) ='2016-02-12')
  SET @i = @i+2
END
SELECT * FROM @T
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare @i as int

Declare @dr as date

Set @i = 1

while @i < 8

Begin

SELECT @dr = DATEADD(DAY, @i, '2016-02-07')

while (((DATEPART(dw, @dr) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (5, 6))

```
begin
     print @dr
     break;
end
```

Set @i = @i +1

End

go

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```sql
SELECT   inp.d AS [Start_Date]
        ,incr.r AS Increment
        ,DATEADD(DAY, incr.r, inp.d) AS New_Date
        ,FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, incr.r, inp.d), 'ddd') AS New_Date_Weekday
FROM (
    -- Input date goes here
    SELECT   CAST('2016-02-07' AS DATE) AS d
) inp
CROSS JOIN
    (
        -- Generate 7 rows
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1 AS r
        FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) v(n)
) incr

-- Convert week-day to 'Monday = 1 and Sunday = 7'-base;
-- Select a random week-day between 1 and 5
WHERE 1 + ( 5 + DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(DAY, incr.r, inp.d)) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 = 1 + CAST(RAND() * 5 AS INT)
```

Thanks to [Kakkarot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21784349/1110897) for his answer explaining how to convert week-day count to be based on *Monday = 1 and Sunday = 7*.