# Get data in groups of "Week of..." when dates may be missing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data in a table with dates, and want to count the rows by "Week of" (e.g., "Week of 2017-05-01"), where the result has the week's date (starting on Mondays) and the count of matching rows — even if there are no rows for that week. (This will all be in a date range.)

I can partition things into weeks readily enough by grouping on `DATEPART(wk, D)` (where `D` is the date column), but I'm struggling with:

1. How to get the "Week of" date and fill, and
2. How to have a row for a week where there are no matching rows in the data

Here's grouping by week:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
SET DATEFIRST 1; -- Monday is first day of week

DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '2017-05-01';
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '2017-07-01';

SELECT      DATEPART(wk, D) AS [Week Number], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM        #temp
GROUP BY    DATEPART(wk, D)
ORDER BY    DATEPART(wk, D);
```

Which gives me:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−+
| Week Number | Count |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−+
| 19          |     5 |
| 20          |    19 |
| 22          |     8 |
| 23          |    10 |
| 24          |     5 |
| 26          |     4 |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−+
```

But ideally I want:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−+
| Week       | Count |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−+
| 2017-05-01 |     5 |
| 2017-05-08 |    19 |
| 2017-05-15 |     0 |
| 2017-05-22 |     8 |
| 2017-05-29 |    10 |
| 2017-06-05 |     5 |
| 2017-06-12 |     0 |
| 2017-06-19 |     4 |
| 2017-06-26 |     0 |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−+
```

How can I do that?

---

Set up information for testing:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    D DATETIME
);
GO

INSERT INTO #temp (D)
VALUES      -- Week of 2017-05-01 (#19)
            ('2017-05-01'),('2017-05-01'),('2017-05-01'),
            ('2017-05-06'),('2017-05-06'),
            -- Week of 2017-05-08 (#20) - note no data actually on the 8th
            ('2017-05-10'),
            ('2017-05-11'),('2017-05-11'),('2017-05-11'),('2017-05-11'),('2017-05-11'),('2017-05-11'),
            ('2017-05-12'),('2017-05-12'),('2017-05-12'),('2017-05-12'),
            ('2017-05-13'),('2017-05-13'),('2017-05-13'),('2017-05-13'),('2017-05-13'),('2017-05-13'),('2017-05-13'),
            ('2017-05-14'),
            -- Week of 2017-05-15 (#21)
            -- (note we have no data for this week)
            -- Week of 2017-05-22 (#22)
            ('2017-05-22'),('2017-05-22'),('2017-05-22'),
            ('2017-05-23'),('2017-05-23'),('2017-05-23'),('2017-05-23'),('2017-05-23'),
            -- Week of 2017-05-29 (#23)
            ('2017-05-29'),('2017-05-29'),('2017-05-29'),
            ('2017-06-02'),('2017-06-02'),
            ('2017-06-03'),
            ('2017-06-04'),('2017-06-04'),('2017-06-04'),('2017-06-04'),
            -- Week of 2017-06-05 (#24) - note no data actually on the 5th
            ('2017-06-08'),('2017-06-08'),('2017-06-08'),
            ('2017-06-11'),('2017-06-11'),
            -- Week of 2017-06-12 (#25)
            -- (note we have no data for this week)
            -- Week of 2017-06-19 (#26)
            ('2017-06-19'),('2017-06-19'),('2017-06-19'),
            ('2017-06-20');
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you have to generate a table or CTE with the Monday dates and their week numbers (as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3946151/157247), slightly modified for what we need to do below), then `LEFT JOIN` or `OUTER APPLY` that with your data grouped by week, using the week numbers:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
SET DATEFIRST 1;

DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '2017-05-01';
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '2017-07-01';

;WITH Mondays AS (
    SELECT  @startDate AS D, DATEPART(WK, @startDate) AS W
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 7, D), DATEPART(WK, DATEADD(DAY, 7, D))
    FROM    Mondays m
    WHERE   DATEADD(DAY, 7, D) < @endDate
)
SELECT      LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Mondays.D, 120), 10) AS [Week Of], d.Count
FROM        Mondays
OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) AS [Count]
            FROM    #temp
            WHERE   DATEPART(WK, D) = W
            AND     D >= @startDate
            AND     D < @endDate
) d
ORDER BY    Mondays.D;
```

Two notes on that:

1. I'm assuming we can ensure that `@startDate` is a Monday, which is easily done outside the query or could be done with a simple loop in T-SQL if needed (backing up until `WEEKPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate)` is `1`). (Or worst case we could generate all the dates and then filter them with `WEEKPART(WEEKDAY, ...)`.)
2. I'm assuming the date range is always a year or less; otherwise, we'd have duplicated week numbers. If the date range could be longer than a year, combine the week number with the year everywhere we're just using a week number above (e.g., `DATEPART(YEAR, D) * 100 + DATEPART(wk, D)`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
SET DATEFIRST 1; -- Monday is first day of week

DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '2017-05-01';
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '2017-07-01';

;WITH OrgResult AS ( -- Grouping result with missing week. Answer of the first question
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART (WEEKDAY, D), D) [Week] -- Fist Day Of the Week
        , COUNT(*) [Count]
    FROM #temp
        WHERE D BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    GROUP BY 
        DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART (WEEKDAY, D), D)
)
, Result AS -- Adds only missing weeks. Answer of the second question
(
    SELECT * FROM OrgResult
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD( DAY, 7, R.[Week] ), 0 [Count] 
    FROM Result R 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM OrgResult O WHERE [Week] = DATEADD( DAY, 7, R.[Week] ) )
            AND DATEADD( DAY, 7, R.[Week] ) <= @endDate
)
SELECT * FROM Result
ORDER BY [Week]
```

Result:

```
Week        Count
----------- -----------
2017-05-01  5
2017-05-08  19
2017-05-15  0
2017-05-22  8
2017-05-29  10
2017-06-05  5
2017-06-12  0
2017-06-19  4
2017-06-26  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. I included this as it will generate less reads than the Recursive CTE Solution and will be a lot fast

```
WITH E(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))x(x)),
iTally(N) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (((DATEDIFF(day,@startdate, @endDate))/7)+1)
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1)
  FROM E a, E b, E c
)
SELECT WeekOf = DATEADD(WEEK,N,@startDate), [count] = COUNT(t.D)
FROM iTally i
LEFT JOIN #temp t ON t.D >= DATEADD(WEEK,N,@startDate) AND t.D < DATEADD(WEEK,N+1,@startDate)
GROUP BY DATEADD(WEEK,N,@startDate)
ORDER BY DATEADD(WEEK,N,@startDate); -- not required
```

Results:

```
WeekOf     count
---------- -----------
2017-05-01 5
2017-05-08 19
2017-05-15 0
2017-05-22 8
2017-05-29 10
2017-06-05 5
2017-06-12 0
2017-06-19 4
2017-06-26 0
```