# Display dates in between dates in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a simple table below with 5 records.

```
Id:    Date
123    9/1/15
123
123
123
123    9/5/15
```

How do I write in SQL server to display the missing dates from 9/2/15 to 9/4/15?

I was thinking about using a loop but my skills are not there yet. Basically, I like to know how to write a SQL script that displays the missing dates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Dates between a range of dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271595/getting-dates-between-a-range-of-dates)

Comment: This is a use case for a calendar table, plenty of good articles on that, and an outer join to that.  A loop will work, but won't perform nearly as well as a table that contains a list of dates.

Comment: Hi Hart, would you please show me such articles?

Comment: Hi Ruben,  I look into those but not exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: You should include your rdbms name, `SQL SERVER`, `MySQL`

Comment: @ juan, It is SQL SERVER 2006-2012

Comment: if the dates are missing, how u figure it out the date? column can either have a date or not.. and u want to search for date that is missing and the date between 9/2 and 9/4???  aren't they mutually exclusive?

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for your feedback and assistance. I have not got a chance to review your help since I asked the question. Thanks a gain, forks! Joe.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want something like this:

```
WITH T(ID, Date, MaxDate) AS (
    SELECT ID, MIN(Date), MAX(Date) FROM MyTable GROUP BY ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, DATEADD(day, 1, Date), MaxDate FROM T WHERE Date < MaxDate 
)
SELECT ID, Date FROM T ORDER BY ID, Date
```

Please follow this fiddle to see it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/682180/2/0

Credit: my query is largely based on this answer (proposed by Rubens): [Getting Dates between a range of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271595/getting-dates-between-a-range-of-dates#271878)

I must say that I don't like the idea of the database layer being responsible for representation of data.
Please consider doing a repair on the table itself, filling in the missing dates.
Though I have no idea how; there seems to be no unique identifier to tell the three NULL records apart.
You may want to take this back to the source of the data; looks like you have been importing an Excel sheet.
Try to repair it there.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
DECLARE @TMP TABLE ( ID INT, ADMIT DATE )

INSERT INTO @TMP ( ID, ADMIT )
VALUES   ( 123, '2015-09-01' )
        ,( 123, NULL )
        ,( 123, NULL )
        ,( 123, NULL )
        ,( 123, '2015-09-05' )

SELECT TMP.ID
      ,CASE 
          WHEN TMP.ADMIT IS NULL
             THEN DATEADD(D,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TMP.ID, TMP.ADMIT ORDER BY TMP.ID ASC)),B.MIN_ADMIT)
          ELSE TMP.ADMIT 
       END  AS NEW_DATE
FROM @TMP AS TMP
      INNER JOIN ( SELECT ID, MIN(ADMIT) AS MIN_ADMIT
                   FROM @TMP
                   GROUP BY ID
                 ) B ON B.ID = TMP.ID
ORDER BY TMP.ID, NEW_DATE ASC
```

Basically, this just creates a temp table with your dummy data so we can test with some values.  Then performs the query that uses a row ranking for each row number and add's that value to the minimum date found in the original list...

We need the `INNER JOIN` because we need to do a `GROUP BY` clause to get the `MIN` date from your original table.  We can't do a `GROUP BY` in our original `SELECT` because that will begin excluding some rows as we only have `ID` and `ADMIT` to group off of; therefore the 3 records will `NULL` would be truncated to 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

try using MINUS - demonstrated below for numbers, you can use it for dates.
MINUS should make the query maintainable and it will simply the query.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fae97/4)

**Query 1**:

```
select n from
 ( select rownum n from dual connect by level <= 5)
 where n >= 1
 MINUS
 select n from
 ( select rownum n from dual connect by level <= 2)
 where n >= 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fae97/4/0)**:
    | N |
    |---|
    | 3 |
    | 4 |
    | 5 |

Hope it will help you :)