# Report Builder throws error over types mismatch in recursive CTE

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0, recursive-cte

I'm using a Recursive CTE I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271595/getting-dates-between-a-range-of-dates)  to get dates within a range:

```
WITH T(d)
AS
( 
SELECT @DateFrom 
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(DateAdd(DD,1,T.d) AS DATETIME) FROM T WHERE T.d < @DateTo
)
SELECT d FROM T OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

This CTE runs fine on my SQL Server, but when trying to create a dataset with this query in Report Builder 3.0 I'm getting the Define Query Parameters dialog (which I usually gon't get) and after clicking OK I get the error: `Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "d" of recursive query "T".`

I know `DATEADD` returns `SMALLDATETIME`, and I though Report Builder passes `DATETIME` into `@DateFrom`  so I thought CASTing the return value of `DATEADD` to a `DATETIME` will solve it, but it didn't.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch, try the following:-

```
WITH T(d)
AS
( 
SELECT cast(@DateFrom as datetime) as d
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(DateAdd(DD,1,T.d) AS DATETIME) FROM T WHERE T.d < @DateTo
)
SELECT d FROM T OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. Do you know what is the type of the date parameter sent by Report Builder? It is clearly not DATETIME...

Comment: And after casting @DateFrom in the anchor part, I didn't even need the cast in the recursive part.

Comment: @OzW if you see the parameter properties, it just has one date option. I guess thats not similar to SQL Server datetime type.